# Is there a function to hide duplicates in one column although the other columns contain different values?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I created a table with information from several tables. The result of the table looks like this:

[image]

and I want like this:

[image]

The article number occurs several times. I would like only one article number. It doesn't matter which row is hidden. It is important that only one article. The sorting should then still be according to `erranf_zeit` in ascending order.

My PHP code and query in MS SQL looks like this:

```php
    if( $conn ) 
    {
        # echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Es konnte leider keine Verbindung aufgebaut werden.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    
    $query ="SELECT TOP 30 m.artikel,b.order, z.plan_auftrag, m.bez_1, m.bez_2, m.artikel_bez, b.masch_nr, b.erranf_zeit,b.erranf_dat, s.a_status";
    $query.=" FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz] z";
    $query.=" JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b";
    $query.=" ON z.auftrag_nr = b.aunr";
    $query.=" JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrag_status] s";
    $query.=" ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr";
    $query.=" JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[mlst_hy] m";
    $query.=" ON s.auftrag_nr = m.auftrag_nr";  
    $query.=" AND s.a_status IN ('V','L')";
    $query.=" AND m.kennz = 'M'";
    $query.=" AND s.eingeplant = ('M')";
    
    if (isset($_GET['maschine']) AND $_GET['maschine'] > '0')
    {   
        $query.=" AND b.masch_nr='$_GET[maschine]'";    
    }
    $query.=" ORDER BY s.a_status ASC, b.erranf_dat ASC, b.erranf_zeit ASC";
    
    
    //SELECT COUNT(*), m.artikel
    //FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[mlst_hy] m
    //GROUP BY m.artikel
    //HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
    
  
    $i='';

    $trenner = '';

    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
    {
            
        if ($row['artikel'] != $trenner)
            
        {

        echo "<tr class=grey>";
        
            echo "<td>$row[artikel]</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['plan_auftrag'];          
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['bez_1'];
            echo "</td>";
         
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['bez_2'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['artikel_bez'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['masch_nr'];
            echo "</td>";
            
            echo "<td>";
    echo substr($row['erranf_dat']->format('d.m.Y H:i:s:u'), 0, -16);
    echo " - ";
            echo gmdate("H:i", $row['erranf_zeit']);
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            
                if ($row['a_status']=="E")
                {
                echo "beendet";
                }
                else if ($row['a_status']=="L")
                {
                echo "laufend";
                }
                else if ($row['a_status']=="V")
                {
                echo "vorbereitet";
                }
                else if ($row['a_status']=="U")
                {
                echo "unterbrochen";
                }
            
            echo "</td>";
            
            echo "</tr>";       
            
        }

    $trenner = $row['artikel'];         

    }

}
```

Comment: It comes down to `GROUP BY` and something like `MIN(ERRANF_ZEIT)`.  It would be extremely helpful to have the sample data (current and expected) as text instead of a picture.  Also, which database, as this affects what sql options are available. A minor issue- if you use something like a [heredoc or a nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), you can present the query without having to mentally filter out all the echoes and quotes. I might be able to help more, but I have to overcome the language barrier along with mental filtering

Comment: So, instead of wrapping the entire `<tr>` into `if ($row['artikel'] != $trenner)`, only wrap the output of `$row[artikel]` in it?

Comment: the $trenner should hide dublicate that are below each other. he does that as soon as they stand together. but only then.